# Are there any ships that go from Australia/New Zealand to Kiribati?

Tags: australia, sea-travel, new-zealand, ships, kiribati

Note: I am not particularly interested in cruise ships.

I am in need of information of any vessels that would go from any port in Australia or New Zealand to Kiribati, it does not matter if it stops at other places along the way.

Who would I contact and how much would it cost (approximately)?

Answer (score 4):

The only person I know who's visited Kiribati by boat is Graham Hughes of "[201 countries by land](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2239087/Graham-Hughes-British-man-person-visit-201-countries-WITHOUT-using-plane.html)" fame, who managed to blag his way onto the [Southern Pearl](http://dieselship.com/ships-database/1086-southern_pearl.html) to [Kiribati](http://www.theodysseyexpedition.com/tag/kiribati).  But it's a working cargo ship, so don't expect getting permission from owners [Neptune Pacific Line](http://www.neptunepacific.com/) to be easy, plus their website also doesn't list service to Kiribati at the moment.  Good luck!

[Swire](http://www.swireshipping.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=49&Itemid=44) and [Kyowa](http://www.kyowa-line.co.jp/service/service2_en.html) also claim to serve Tarawa (Kiribati) occasionally.

Comment: Thank you for the information and for insulting my friends' homeland

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an insult, but a factual assessment of what this looks like: http://www.asa-agency.com/media/7b579dc4-c92d-11e1-82ec-77cd6bcd5eaf-trash-dump-on-betio-island-s-tarawa-the-most-densely-populat#.UsJCN43LGf0

Comment: +1 for the info though I wouldn't offer the same qualification based on a pictures from what I can tell taken 13 years ago.

Comment: I wouldn't call an undated random picture from a random photographer a factual assessment ... But if you insist, other pictures tell a different story http://www.asa-agency.com/-/galleries/viajes-destinos/kiribati-oceania

Comment: I'm not basing my opinion on a random picture. But I've removed my personal assessment of this tropical idyll since it's not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Cargo ships take limited numbers of paying passengers. On average you pay $100 per day you spend on a ship, which makes knowing the total price a bit unpredictable.

[cargoshipcruises](http://www.cargoshipcruises.nl/english.html) offers complete intineraries. I am not familiar with the names of Kiribati's port, but I would suggest contacting cargoshipcruises for advice.